# Error thrown in Webclient even after doOnError

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, webclient

I am using `WebClient` to make an api call. In few of the error responses from API, **response body is empty** and in few errors **there is an error body**, I need to extract certain text from the error response body and send it in the `Throwable` for logging. I am using `exchangeToMono()` to serve this purpose as below. In cases when `there is an error body`, my `WebClientResponseException` is getting thrown, However even after handling it the `throwable` in `doOnError()`, same exception is getting thrown and the outside `catch` block is also getting executed. Is the exception being thrown even after `doOnError()`?

```
try{

    getWebClient().
    patch().
    uri(uri).
    body(fromValue(getBody())).
    exchangeToMono (clientResponse -> {
    
    if(clientResponse.statusCode().isError()){
    
    return clientResponse.
    bodyToMono(APIresponse.class).
    switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new WebClientResponseException(clientResponse.statusCode().value(), clientResponse.statusCode().getReasonPhrase(),null,null,CharSet.defaultCharset()))).
    flatmap(apiresponse -> Mono.error(new WebClientResponseException(clientResponse.statusCode().value(), apiresponse.getResponseMessage(),null,null,CharSet.defaultCharset())));        
      }    
     }
    ).
     doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error Text {}",throwable.getMessage())).
     block();
}

catch(Exception exception){
log.error("Exception from api call");
}
```

Comment: Never use `block()` and must not also to block the thread in the reactive environment!

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnError-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: doOnError() actualy does not handle your exception but just applies some side effect (just for logging something and etc.). To actually handle exceptions you should use operators like onErrorResume/Return/Continue()